# point multiple ip address to hosting

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, dns, ip

I have centos server, earlier it had 1 ip [ `a.b.c.d` ] (external ip , eg., `141.101.114.59`).

Now, I bought 2 additional ip [`b.c.d.e` , `f.g.h.i`] (external ip , e.g, `190.93.244.58` , `130.93.245.8` ). I have setup two virtual interface with those IPs.

```
ifcfg-eth0:0
ifcfg-eth0:1
```

When I am pinging from my system to my additional IPs, it says `Request time out`. But when I ping it locally, it works.

The two new IPs are not pingable from my system to the server. How can I fix this?

Comment: More information is required - are the new IP's from the same provider ?  [How] have you programmed in the gateway ?     The problem sounds like it could be a source-routing problem, but it could simply be that your new IP's are in a different block and the gateway is not [correctly] set up - a lot more detail of your network is required to form a cogent answer.

Comment: Yes, all ip from same provider. Kindly let me know what command to run for your query.

Comment: /sbin/ifconfig; /sbin/ip route show   will print out your interfaces and routing table.  How do you connect your machines together ?  (We probably need similar information for the router/gateway)

Comment: It's not a multiple machine. It is one single machine, where i am configuring multiple ip address, all i want, that, all my IP address can pin and connect to server.

for e.g, when i do SSH to a.b.c.d , i can also do SSH to d.e.f.g and do SSH to g.h.i.j

Comment: Currently i am only able to SSH to a.b.c.d

Comment: Did you try stopping your firewall and pinging `[b.c.d.e , f.g.h.i]`? If not try `/etc/init.d/iptables stop` and see if you can reach them. Also, include following outputs in your original post: `ifconfig`, `route -n` & `uname -a`